# Open a div at place clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a rather simple question but i can't seem to find an answer to it.
I want when i click on any place on web page a div is opened. how can i accomplish that CSS style.
My question is about the position of the div if i add this div inside a table and i want it to be opened each time i click on different rows.
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp + http://api.jquery.com/click/ + http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm try something like this:

```
<table>
<tr onclick="d=document.getElementById('myDiv');if(d.style.display=='block'){d.style.display='none';}else{d.style.display='block';}">
 <td><td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="d=document.getElementById('myDiv');if(d.style.display=='block'){d.style.display='none';}else{d.style.display='block';}">
 <td><td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="myDiv" style="display:none">
STuff
</div>
```

There are better ways to do this.. Im not sure if the tr tag has an onclick handler but its worth a try. You could use a javascript library like [jquery](http://jquery.com) or [mootools](http://mootools.net).